# Is it possible to do a TWRP restore from laptop - would adb restore do the same? Other ways to perform restore?

Tags: twrp, restore

This is a pretty annoying situation I've found myself in.

A section of my screen has become non-responsive, sort of across the top, where the top row of digits would be.

I read online that a possible fix would be performing a factory reset. which I did. Didn't solve the issue, so I think the digitizer might be damaged somewhat, which I'm going to look into getting repaired.

Anyway, I had previously done a backup of my data through TWRP but, wouldn't you know it, the section that is nonresponsive falls exactly where the Backup/Restore buttons are, so I can't restore my data now.

Are there alternative means for me to restore this data? I know there's a thing called adb restore, but I'm not sure if it's the same and wanted to make sure before toying with anything.

I know that TWRP has a Terminal under Advanced. Is it possible to do anything with that?

The bootloader on the phone is unlocked and was rooted, up until now, I guess.

EDIT:

OK. I figured out that you can use adb through TWRP recovery.

adb shell twrp restore

However when I do this through CMD it says no partitions selected.

Any idea?

Comment: This would help you for sure: http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/OpenRecoveryScript. Read it from "The following commands and parameters are available"

Comment: You need to supply the filename of the backup file. Did you move your TWRP backup to your PC?